# Islam, being a muslim

Tags: muslim-practices

I am Muslim and i saw something online about prophet Muhammad that made me  upset so i started researching about his life and his wives online. I had some negative feelings toward him but I quickly stopped. I feel guilty, does this make me a disbeliever now?

Comment: There are things that, when misunderstood, can absolutely make you have negative thoughts / feelings. You need to hear them portrayed in the correct context. For example, a lot of bad things have been said about the marriage to Fathima رضى الله تعالى عنها due to her age that once you understand in the context of the time it is completey reasonable and normal. Only recently (as recently as 100 years ago) has marriage to minors been deemed a bad thing or even illegal in many countries.

Comment: So would doing this make me a disbeliever now?

Comment: Do you believe in Allah and His messenger صلى الله عليه وسلم in your heart? That's all that should matter.

Comment: If you give us an idea of the things you read about, perhaps we can point you to more authentic reports to remove your bad thoughts, إن شاء الله.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you are still a believer if you believe allah and his messenger,sometimes when you misunderstand something you think its bad but safe sidedly to astaghfar and even if it was considered as asin it will be forgived

Answer (score 0):

Bismillahi Ar-Rahmaan Ar-Raheem

If you did not affirm it, or believe in it, then you are not a disbeliever. Do not be swayed by the tricks of Shayateen among men and jinn. You can be sure 100% of such claims are (as you will see In Sha Allah) laughable. However, you should do your best to resolve doubts as soon as possible. Here is a useful resource for solving common doubts.

https://defendingislam.github.io/